# Como atribuir um checked no checkbox com foreach

Tags: php, laravel

Eu quero fazer um esquema com PHP(Laravel) com as checkbox onde recebo os valores delas do banco, seleciono e salvo numa tabela a parte. Quando eu recupero, quero comparar pra fazer um checked nas que estiverem lá. Porém, a forma que estou fazendo, faz com que repitam os campos novamente. Como posso fazer isso?

```
                 @foreach ($linguagens as $linguagem)
                    @foreach ($minhasl as $minhal)
                        @if($minhal->linguagem_id == $linguagem->id)
                            <div class="form-check mb-5">
                                <input class="form-check-input" checked type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="{{$linguagem->id}}"  id="flexCheckDefault">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="{{$linguagem->linguagem}}">
                                {{$linguagem->linguagem}}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        @else
                            <div class="form-check mb-5">
                                <input class="form-check-input"  type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="{{$linguagem->id}}"  id="flexCheckDefault">
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="{{$linguagem->linguagem}}">
                                {{$linguagem->linguagem}}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
```

Comment: Salve! Edite sua pergunta e coloque o conteúdo de `$linguagens` e `$minhasl`, bem como o print do resultado obtido.

Answer (score -2):

```
    @foreach ($linguagens as $linguagem)
    @foreach ($minhasl as $minhal)
        <div class="form-check mb-5">
            <input class="form-check-input" {{ $minhal->linguagem_id == $linguagem->id ? 'checked' : " }} type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="{{$linguagem->id}}"  id="flexCheckDefault">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="{{$linguagem->linguagem}}">
                            {{$linguagem->linguagem}}
                    </label>
                 </div>
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Você pode usar operador ternário veja: [link Operador documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php)

Primeiro declaramos a condição; logo após o sinal de interrogação (?), o código a ser executado caso a condição seja verdadeira; e depois dos dois pontos, o código a ser executado caso contrário.

Sintaxe do operador ternário:

```
condição ? codigoUm : codigoDois;

{{ $minhal->linguagem_id == $linguagem->id ? 'checked' : " }}
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).